# Does `Fish` change the order of $PATH? How to avoid that

Tags: macos, shell, path, rvm, fish

```
fish --version
> fish, version 3.0.2

uname -a
> Darwin Jerrys-MacBook.local 18.6.0 Darwin Kernel Version 18.6.0: Thu Apr 25 23:16:27 PDT 2019; root:xnu-4903.261.4~2/RELEASE_X86_64 x86_64

echo $TERM
> xterm-256color
```

I have compare my $PATH in bash and `fish` shell, the order of `rvm` changed, which cause `which pod` become different(i used `rvm` to manage `ruby`).

How can I make them same order ?

By the way,

- I have include all my setting in `.bashrc` and load it by `source ~/.bashrc` in `.bash_profile`, noting in `.prfile`
- And I have nothing in `~/.config/fish/config.fish`

The begin character of `x`,`~`,`=`,`>` just I added mark to compare easily.

```
----- echo $PATH

=:~/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.9/bin
=:~/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.9@global/bin
=:~/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.9/bin
X=:/opt/local/bin
X=:/opt/local/sbin
=:~/.nvm/versions/node/v8.11.3/bin
~:/usr/local/bin
~:/usr/bin
~:/bin
~:/usr/sbin
~:/sbin
>:/usr/local/share/dotnet
>:/opt/X11/bin
>:/Library/Frameworks/Mono.framework/Versions/Current/Commands
X-:~/.rvm/bin
X-:~/.local/bin
X-:/usr/local/Cellar/aria2/1.33.1/bin
X-:~/Documents/code/flutter/sdk/flutter/bin
X-:~/Documents/code/flutter/sdk/flutter/bin/cache/dart-sdk/bin
X-:~/Documents/code/flutter/sdk/flutter/.pub-cache/bin
```

```
------ fish & echo $PATH

~/usr/local/bin
~/usr/bin
~/bin
~/usr/sbin
~/sbin
>/opt/X11/bin
>/usr/local/share/dotnet
>/Library/Frameworks/Mono.framework/Versions/Current/Commands
=~/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.9/bin
=~/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.9@global/bin
=~/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.9/bin
X=/opt/local/bin
X=/opt/local/sbin
=~/.nvm/versions/node/v8.11.3/bin
X-~/.rvm/bin
X-~/.local/bin
X-/usr/local/Cellar/aria2/1.33.1/bin
X-~/Documents/code/flutter/sdk/flutter/bin
X-~/Documents/code/flutter/sdk/flutter/bin/cache/dart-sdk/bin
X-~/Documents/code/flutter/sdk/flutter/.pub-cache/bin
```

Comment: looks like it's issue since fish3.0 https://github.com/fish-shell/fish-shell/issues/5456

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a simple workaround from [this PR](https://github.com/fish-shell/fish-shell/pull/5956),

```sh
# Download patched config
curl -O https://raw.githubusercontent.com/fish-shell/fish-shell/e18354bc6ef937e2e663fc098cc51a2546d4d2d0/share/config.fish

# Install config
mv config.fish /usr/local/share/fish/
```

Comment: I have re download the installer `fish-3.0.2.pkg` from https://fishshell.com/, and do the steps of yours, then type`fish` will get error `/usr/local/share/fish/config.fish (line 239): Unknown builtin ''
        builtin $jobbltn (__fish_expand_pid_args $argv)` , I guess because the other file in `/usr/local/share/` not match.

Comment: Hmm, that must be an unrelated change; this diff shows the actual differences from the PR, https://github.com/fish-shell/fish-shell/pull/5956/files

Answer (score 0):

here how i solved it (using fish only as interactive on top of my zsh):

in `.zshrc`:

```
export ZSHPATH="$PATH"

fish
```

in `.config/fish/config.fish`

```
set PATH $ZSHPATH $PATH
```

Comment: Would you provide which version you use too? Because I simple use back to an old version, and issue gone for me.

Answer (score -1):

To be simple,  download & install the version [fish-2.7.1.pkg](https://github.com/fish-shell/fish-shell/releases/download/2.7.1/fish-2.7.1.pkg) which don't have this bug on Mac.

According to code commit, next version `fish-3.1.0` may fix this bug.